# jQuery Change all names of div's children elements after clone

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

So, I have the following jquery code that clones an element when the input value in a certain field increases.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nmovimentos").change(function () {
        var direction = this.defaultValue < this.value
        this.defaultValue = this.value;
        if (direction)
        {
                var $div = $('div[id^="novomov"]:last');
                var num = parseInt( $div.prop("id").match(/\d+/g), 10 ) +1;
                var $clone = $div.clone().prop('id', 'novomov'+ num)
                $clone.insertAfter('[id^="novomov"]:last');
        }
        else $('[id^="novomov"]:last').remove();
    });
});
```

However, it clones a div that contains part of a form with lots of input fields.

```
<div id="novomov1" class="novomov">
<table id="tab">
<tr name="linear1" id="linear1">
        <td>
            Cardinalidade:<input type="text" name="card1" id="card1" value=""><br>
            Angulo 1:<input type="text" name="param1" id="angulo1" value=""><br>
            Angulo 2:<input type="text" name="param2" id="angulo2" value=""><br>
            Tamanho:<input type="text" name="param3" id="tamanho1" value=""><br>
            Descricao:<input type="text" name="descricao1" id="descricao1" value=""><br>
            Tempo:<input type="text" name="tempo1" id="tempo1" value=""><br>
        </td></tr></table></div>
```

I need to change the names of all the cloned div's descendents, in order to pass these paramaters to a data base. I thought of incrementing the names by 1, using the var num in the jquery function. However I'm I little lost.. so, any clues on how to do that? thank you very much!

Comment: In which element do you want it to be appended? Can you add ```$('.main-element').append($clone)``` instead of ```$clone.insertAfter('[id^="novomov"]:last');```?

Comment: Create a variable outside your change function, then increment it (`++`) with each iteration of the function. Use it in your name attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code changed to retrieve all the inputs inside the cloned div and change its name/id.

```
<script>    
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#nmovimentos").change(function () {
                var direction = this.defaultValue < this.value
                this.defaultValue = this.value;
                if (direction)
                {
                        var $div = $('div[id^="novomov"]:last');
                        var num = parseInt( $div.prop("id").match(/\d+/g), 10 ) +1;
                        var $clone = $div.clone().prop('id', 'novomov'+ num)
                        $clone.insertAfter('[id^="novomov"]:last');
                        // get all the inputs inside the clone
                        var inputs = $clone.find('input');
                        // for each input change its name/id appending the num value
                        $.each(inputs, function(index, elem){
                            var jElem = $(elem); // jQuery element
                            var name = jElem.prop('name');
                            // remove the number
                            name = name.replace(/\d+/g, '');
                            name += num;
                            jElem.prop('id', name);
                            jElem.prop('name', name);
                        });
                }
                else $('[id^="novomov"]:last').remove();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked! Actually, I would like for all the descendents to have the names changed, not only the inputs.. but I guess I can do the same thing if instead of `$clone.find('input')` I put  `$clone.find(*)` or `$clone.children()` ?

Comment: children function reaches only the first child layer. Use the find function to get all child nodes

Comment: `$clone.find('*');` isn't working.. any suggestion? :(

Answer (score 1):

Instead of parsing the id of the element to get the number you should use the data attribute. Also since you are using jQuery you can use `.last()` to get the last element with that id. Hope this helps.

```
     $('#nmovimentos').on('change', function () {
        var direction = this.defaultValue < this.value,
            $last = $('#novomov').last(),
            $clone,
            num;

        this.defaultValue = this.value;

        if (direction) {
            // add id in a data attribute instead of parsing the id
            num = parseInt($last.data('id'), 10) + 1;

            // set clone id data attribute to have the latest number
            $clone = $last.clone().data('id', num);

            // add clone after the last div
            $last.after($clone);
        } else {
            $last.remove();  
        }
    });
```